# add icon to tab in backend edit page magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, tabs, icon

I'm using this to add tab:

```
$this->addTab('sliders_section_new', array(
            'title'     => Mage::helper('sm_cameraslider')->__('New Sliders'),
            'label'     => "<i class='fa fa-puzzle-piece'></i>".Mage::helper('sm_cameraslider')->__('New Sliders'),
            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('sm_cameraslider/adminhtml_sliders_edit_tab_main')->toHtml()
        ));
```

I want to show an icon in the tab so I added below code:

```
"<i class='fa fa-puzzle-piece'></i>"
```

but it not work. now it's showing

[image]

is there any way to add icon in the tab? thank for helping me.